# Django encrypted paypal m2crypto python3, error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-forms

I added the integration of Paypal with Django with the help of django-paypal, but I have a problem.

I use the `PaypalPaymentForm` form, but it is possible to modify the values ​​of that form, And I don't want that to happen.

The solution I found was to use the `PayPalEncryptedPaymentsForm` form, so you cannot modify the values ​​per form.

The problem is that I need the ***M2Crypto*** library, which is only available in *python2*, and I am using *python3* and *Django2.2.2*.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

---

I also tried to install the library by pip, but it gives me an error.

I saw that there is a somewhat similar form called `PayPalSharedSecretEncryptedPaymentsForm`, I did not quite understand how it works, is this form an alternative to the `PayPalEncryptedPaymentsForm` form?

Documentation about *django-paypal*: https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: What makes you say that m2crypto is only available on Python 2? The package supports Python 3 up to 3.7. https://pypi.org/project/M2Crypto/0.35.2/

Comment: At the time of installing it by pip gives error, you know why?

Comment: Error: `error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
`

Comment: That means something failed to compile - would need to see the whole stack trace to know what.

Comment: I asked another question with the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426546/fatal-error-openssl-err-h-no-such-file-or-directory-python/59426571